# Google Glass LED won't turn on when power button pushed

Tags: google-glass

My Google Glass won't turn on when I press the power button. The LED doesn't even light up when pressed. I charge it and the light stays on, solid, and not pulsating, so it is charged, but it just won't turn on. The LED nor the screen do anything when I press any buttons. Any ideas as to what the problem is?

Comment: Is this a new device? It could just be broken.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities about what the problem might be, ranging from the hardware locking up to a more fundamental failure.

You might want to start by doing a hard boot. Hold the power button down for at least 15 seconds, then release it. Then press the button again to try and turn it on.

If this doesn't work, you best bet is to contact a Glass Guide to have them troubleshoot further and possibly do an exchange. See https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3079854 for contact options.